# C++ error: ‘::close’ has not been declared miniSAT

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm trying to embed miniSAT 1.14 to my program.
I need to add the namespace to all the file.

```
#include "File.h"

void File::open(int file_descr, FileMode m, bool own)
{
    if (fd != -1) ::close(fd);
    fd     = file_descr;
    mode   = m;
    own_fd = own;
    pos    = 0;
    buf    = xmalloc<uchar>(File_BufSize);
    if (mode == READ) size = read(fd, buf, File_BufSize);
    else              size = -1;
}
//........
```

when I try to add namespace "miniSAT"

```
#include "File.h"
namespace minisat{

void File::open(int file_descr, FileMode m, bool own)
{
    if (fd != -1) ::close(fd);
    fd     = file_descr;
    mode   = m;
    own_fd = own;
    pos    = 0;
    buf    = xmalloc<uchar>(File_BufSize);
    if (mode == READ) size = read(fd, buf, File_BufSize);
    else              size = -1;
}
```

I encounter the following error
    error: ‘::close’ has not been declared

However in another version of miniSAT I can compile successfully.

Can anyone tell the different between them?

I upload the related codes on the google drive (only three file "File.cpp","File.h","Global.h").

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5t7DJpKfL7UUU1MSXFWZnZDUTg?usp=sharing

The one with suffix '1' is the one I can compile.

But I need to compile another one.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'embed' MiniSAT into your program?

Comment: I mean I need to use it as backend. I use minisat and minisat+ in my program. they have some function and class with same name. so I need to use namespace to distinguish them

Answer (score 1):

MiniSAT wraps its functions within the namespace called `Minisat`, and MiniSAT+ wraps them within the `MiniSat` namespace (note the difference between the two, which is the uppercase 'S' in the second case). C++ is case sensitive, so these are two differenet namespaces and there shouldn't be any name clashes. MiniSAT+ leaves some functions in the global namespace, which is a bad practice, but it seems that MiniSAT on the other hand puts all its functions and classes within the proper namespace, so there should be no name clashes in case of global functions taken from MiniSAT+ either. To sum up: probably you don't need to wrap anything in your own namespace. Just refer to the proper namespace anytime you use functions of the same name. Also note that there will be no name clashes even if the two functions have identical names and live in the same namespace, but take different arguments.

As for your error, you are getting it because you've put the `close()` function inside the `minisat` namespace, whereas the `open()` function calls `::close()`, i.e. it looks for the `close()` function within the global namespace - it's no longer there (it had been there before you moved it to `minisat`), so it cannot be found. You have to modify the way these functions are called if you want to go down this way.

Comment: The minisat I use is v1.14, which I'm sure that this is an old version without wrapping in namespace Minisat. That's why I have to do it myself.
In the miniSAT+ there is a similar file(that I upload with suffix '1' ) which I can successfully wrap in my namespace with the method mention above.
It also come with ::close but it was compile successfully

Comment: If you included both files in your project and used your namespace in only one of them, then the close function from the other file was called and this is why it has compiled successfully. File1.cpp includes File.h, not File1.h

Comment: sorry about the mistack. they were both name with out suffix,  I add it by myself , so it is not an including error , File1.cpp include File1.h, and File1.h include Global.h

Comment: To be more specific, I update the files in the google drive. Now if you type command "make -f makefile1" then the compilation will pass. If you type "make -f makefile", it won't. The only thing I have done to the original file is adding the namespaceto both of them.